# flutter firebase storage issue with image url

Tags: firebase-storage, firebase-console

hello iam new to flutter and firebase , I'm making an ecommerce app using firebase and I want to store images manually in the console in the storage and then retrieve it with all the product value that i have stored in the firestore database , when I upload a new image to my storage there is no url for it , how to get the url and then put it as a string in product document nd get it in flutter ?  [image: Firestorage for my project]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go above the "Size" segment, you'd see a "Name" field that has Hyper-Link on it.
Press on the name and it would transfer you to the URL of the photo
[image]